# how to preserve style when cloning a node

Tags: javascript, dom, styles, traversal, clonenode

I want to take an html document (a book chapter) and separate it into pages (an array of DIV, each containing a page of html content that will fit within the prescribed dimensions of the DIV). I walk the DOM with the following code (found on this site!).

```
function walk(node, func)
{
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node)
    {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};
```

The func function is called test and is below.

```
function test(node)
{
    var copy=node.cloneNode(false);

    currentPageInArray.appendChild(copy);

    //Test if we still fit
    if( $(currentPageInArray).height() <= maxPageHeight )
    {
        //All good
    }
    else
    {
        //We dont fit anymore 
        //Remove node that made us exceed the height
        currentPageInArray.removeChild(copy);

        createNewPage();
        currentPageInArray.appendChild(copy); //into new page
    }
}
```

My pages get generated correctly, however, I lose all styles such as italic, bold, headers, etc. If I try clone(true), many elements get duplicated multiple times. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply styling your content in your style sheets?

Answer (score 1):

You may retrieve the current layout of every element using [currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(IE<9) or [getComputedStyle](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle)(Others) and apply it to the cloned elements.